# Redirecting to other webpage without changing address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a webpage http://example.com. Using the htaccess file I'm redirecting users to the page https://other_domain.com:8081 if they type http://example.com/page in their browser. That works well but the problem is that when redirected, https://other_domain.com:8081 appears in the address bar of the browser. I have added the the following to the top of the htaccess file of the http://example.com webpage but still https://other_domain.com:8081 is shown as the address after redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page(.*)$ https://other_domain.com:8081$1 [L,P]
Redirect /page  https://other_domain.com:8081
```

How can this be resolved so that http://example.com/page is shown in the address bar instead of https://other_domain.com:8081?

Comment: The `P` flag _should_ already accomplish this. Is `mod_proxy` enabled in your server? (I would assume use of the `P` flag to throw an error if it wasn't, but I am not sure.)

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure if it is enabled or not. The problem is I only have access to changes the webpage content but I can't modify stuff on the server.

Comment: You need to check that http server's error log file (or have someone check it). That is where issues with your configuration file will get logged to. This would be required to verify if the proxy module is loaded.

Comment: @arkascha I checked with the administrator of the server. mod_proxy is enabled. Is there something wrong with the lines of code?

Comment: That is why I wrote that you need to check the Http server's error log file. That is where issues are logged along with a pointer to what caused the issue.